# Firebase number authentication not working after uploading app to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, app-store, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an app that verifies a user by their phone number using Firebase phone number authentication.

The Android version is working correctly after it was published of Google Play but the iOS version does not receive SMS messages, despite it working correctly during development testing.

Why might this occur?

When uploaded to Google Play, I was asked to provide SHA key details for my app, but I was not asked or even know what the App Store equivalent is of this procedure.

Comment: I've reworded your question for clarity but I'm still confused. Can you show us some code?

Comment: @Super_Simon There is no code here, its a configuration, I not know what the required configuration in App Store or in firebase after publishing app to app store.

Comment: Have you checked your production certificates in the Apple developer console?

Comment: Yes, my certificates configured correctly.

Comment: You should try to first build and run app in release mode scheme to test and if all are working fine then upload of app store. Because sometime difference behaviour in Debug and Release mode of application.

Comment: @Paul Marshal What exactly means of Release mod, "test it on actual device"?, I do that

Comment: In Xcode Beside Stop button, click on target name, there will be popup open, In that click on `Edit Scheme`. It will open new drop down window. In that click on Info and change Build Configuration to Release. So this will work as app store build.

Comment: @PaulMarshal Thanks for your response, but still have same problem

Comment: @AliA.Jalil, Have you solve this problem? I have same problem.

Comment: it's y using APNs Authentication Key, not certificate.

Comment: facing the same problem, any fix?

Comment: I am using AuthKey and the bundle id on firebase is correct as well. But getting invalid token error, although on release mode the app runs fine. Also I am using flutter.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. 
Check that you have APN certificate for production application set in Firebase or event better set APNs Authentication Key instead of handling separate certificates.

Check here how to generate certificate: https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/how-to-create-an-ios-apns-auth-key

After upload this key to Firebase -> Settings -> Cloud messaging under APN Auth key sections.

Comment: not all heroes wear capes ! this was very hard to find. it wasn't even mentioned in the doc

Comment: Three years passed. but your answer remains highly recommended.

Comment: Perfection... I was using firebase, so for those who is using firebase----> generate .p8 file and key as mentioned above and then add the file and key to firebase console > project setting > cloud messaging > apple app config > add APNs auth keys ---> and then upload the .p8 file and add your key, and you are good to go.